# Is there anything I can do to make "help" load faster in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio, optimization, ide

Loading Help or clicking F1 in Visual Studio is horribly slow to load and has been on ever PC I have installed it on. Is there any optimizations that can be employed to ease this pain?

This is not the same question as [Visual Studio Optimizations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8440/visual-studio-optimizations) I am just trying to solve the problem with help loading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visual Studio (at least 2005 and 2008) defaults to searching online help before local help.

Did you install help locally when you installed Visual Studio?  If you did, is it configured to search local help before searching online help?

FYI, in VS2005 and VS2008 the settings are located in Tools | Options | Environment | Help | Online.

Comment: Embarrassed to say this but, how have I missed this for so long!! Thanks MUCH better!! (and thanks to the rest of you for not closing b4 a helpful answer was submitted!

Answer (score 0):

It is Microsoft's way of reminding you of Benjamin Franklin's famous quote:

> “He that can have Patience, can have what he will.”

... as in this case, ***Help***.

Answer (score -1):

Please refer to: [Some pointers on increasing VS speed.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8440/visual-studio-optimizations)

EDIT: after re-reading the question I see you were looking for speeding up **HELP**, not the IDE in general.

Comment: That covers visual studio in general I am looking for getting the help system to speed up.